# iMac 20inch (Mid 2007) SL DVD Boot Prohibitory Sign

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, installation, dvd

**iMac 20inch (Mid 2007 Build) with Ubuntu 12.0.4**

**How I got in this situation**

I had a perfectly healthy Intel iMac running Snow Leopard several months ago. Then I got the dreaded spinning gear and several kernel panics. After getting a little frustrated (failing to find a solution online), I found an old macbook installation disk and used it to access Disk Utility.

From here, I erased my entire hard drive leaving me with no OS. I then created a Ubuntu DVD and installed Ubuntu onto the system. Now, on Ubuntu, I wine installed Transmac and burned a Single layer copy (with languages, etc. removed to save space) of Snow Leopard onto a 4.7GB DVD. I tried to boot from it and was met with first the grey apple screen and a spinning cog before the grey apple shortly turned into the infamous prohibitory sign.

*Note:* I met this problem previously when using Disk Utility to create a bootable USB of Snow Leopard, hence I severely doubt it has anything to do with the DVD created.

**Resources at my disposal**

- 1 x iMac running Ubuntu
- 6 x 4.7GB DVDs
- 1 x USB Stick 12GB
- 1 x Windows 7 Laptop

**Resources I do not have**

- Firewire cables
- Access to a prebuilt retail disk (Misplaced)
- Access to another Mac
- Apple Warranty

I would be hugely grateful if someone was able to tell me how to install Snow Leopard again.

Comment: Just a note: Your mac will only take 4GB of RAM. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1593

Comment: Also it sounds like your using a pirated or non-apple version of a Snow Leopard install disk. This won't work.

Comment: I've been told 6GB is the maximum I can run whilst maintaining stability. & yes it is but I can't find my legit copy. What else can I do?:/

Comment: Well you were told wrong; the apple website says so. 6GB is a weird number too, not even. It will only take 1/2GB sticks. You can buy a copy online from Amazon, or see if a friend has one.

Comment: I know the 6gb ram installation isn't supported by Apple. It's unorthadox but I will try it anyway. Thanks for your help anyway good friend:)!

Comment: Your processor also doesn't support that much RAM :). Also, snow leopard is still available online http://www.amazon.com/Mac-version-10-6-3-Snow-Leopard/dp/B001AMHWP8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1346510026&sr=8-1&keywords=snow+leopard

Comment: @SimonSheehan Mid 2007 iMac is known to (unofficially) support 6GB of RAM. And Core 2 Duo is 64 bit, supports that much.

Comment: Assuming you have a disk image of Snow Leopard, why did you customize it? Try to burn it as is and see whether that works. 4.7GB should suffice.

Comment: It was a torrented copy and I did it so it would fit on a single layer DVD. I didn't want to pay again after losing my legit copy of it